# jQuery Selector Question

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

***EDIT***: As the below solutions have not worked, I've included more code to be clear.

I am dynamically generating the following html. It basically is a span that's positioned so that whenever productControl is clicked the productMenuHolder div pops up with a menu. Upon mouseleave, the menu disappears.

```
<span class="productControl">
    <div class="productMenuHolder" style="display:none;">
        <ul class="productMenuList">
            <li class="productMenuItem">Menu Item 1</li>
            <li class="productMenuItem">Menu Item 2</li>
            <li class="productMenuItem">Menu Item 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</span>
```

Below is a sample of the jQuery that pops up the menu and hides it when the mouse leaves the menu area.

```
    //shows the hover image 
    $(".productControl").live('hover',function (){$(this).toggleClass("productControl_hover");});

    //pops the menu when productControl is clicked
    $(".productControl").live('click',function(){$(this).find('.productMenuHolder').show();});

    //hides the menu when the mouse leaves the menu
    $('.productMenuHolder').live('mouseleave',function() {$(this).hide();});

    //what i want is to hide the menu when a list item is clicked, however none of the solutions (e.g. closest, find, parent) seem to hide it!
    $('.productMenuHolder li').live('click',function(){ 
    //why are none of the solutions hiding it?
        $(this).closest('.productMenuList').hide();
        $(this).closest('.productMenuHolder').hide();
    });
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Is the approach not working? What are you trying to achieve? It is difficult to tell from reading the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

just do `$('.box').hide();`

if this doesn't work then have you tried putting in an alert in the code to see if the event is firing?

or try two parents as apple is a child of the ul and then you get to the box.

it also depends at what point your creating the live code.  if you create it on document load then it should work.  if however you create it when you create ".box" then it won't work as it hasn't executed.

Comment: $('.box').hide() will hide all boxes. If there was only one, I suspect he would use an ID instead.

Comment: He's not very specific but yeah an id would be ideal

Comment: i actually tried that too, but that doesnt seem to hide it. the event definitely fires off as i checked it with an alert

Answer (score 0):

use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

```
$('.apple').live('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('.box').hide();
});
```

---

or make it in all `li` of `ul` with the `class="fruits"`

```
$('.fruits li').live('click',function(){
   $(this).closest('.box').hide();
});
```

---

**updated answer**

```
//pops the menu when productControl is clicked
$('.fruits li').live('click',function(e){ // pass e as parameter...
   e.stopPropagation();
   $(this).closest('.box').hide();
});
```

use [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) to stop it's parent calling it's click handler which is `$(".productControl").live('click',function(){...});` making it showing again...

---

**another update**

```
$(".productControl").live('click',function(e){
   if ($(e.target).is('li')) return; // <-- add this line...
   //... other codes
});
```

Comment: Thanks Reigel, but it wasn't working so I posted more code to be clear.

Comment: Thanks, great find, but I tried it and still no luck. I checked the reference page you linked and in the comments section someone posted 

"stopPropagation() doesn't work when using .live() to bind events to elements. This should be documented or fixed."

Answer (score 0):

This is the best way to do it:

```
$('.apple').live('click', function() { 
    $(this).closest(".box").hide();
});
```

But using `parents` should also be working (difference is: it will also hide `.box`es further up the DOM tree). If it does not work, we may need to see more of your code.

Comment: The above solutions aren't working. 

I will post more code to be clear.